# How to run multiple functions synchronous in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: selenium, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing, calculation

I try to run multiple functions at the same time in Jupiter Notebook.

I have two web scraping functions that use Selenium and run for an infinite amount of time, both always creating an updated DataFrame. Another function merges the two DataFrames and does some calculations.

As the data always changes and the calculations from the different DataFrames need to be calculated within the same second (The two DataFrames update every 5 seconds), I wonder how I can run all functions at the same time.

As my code is mainly WebScraping I used this more to describe my goal and hopefully make it more readable. I already tried using 'multiprocessing' but it just does not do anything in the notebook.

```
def FirstWebScraping():

  while True:
   time.sleep(5). 
   #getting all data for DataFrame

def SecondtWebScraping():

  while True:
   time.sleep(5). 
   #getting all data for DataFrame


def Calculations():
  while True:
    #merging DataFrame from First- and SecondWebScraping
    #doing calculations
    #running this function infinite and looking for specific values

#Goal
def run_all_at_the_same_time()
  FirstWebScraping()
  SecondWebScraping()
  Calculations()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though threading does not show the same benefits as multiprocessing it worked for me and with selenium. I put a waiting time at the beginning for the Calculations function and from there they were all looped infinitely.

```
from threading import Thread
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = FirstWebScraping).start()
    Thread(target = SecondWebscraping).start()
    Thread(target = Calculations).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run `multiprocessing` in Jupyter, if you follow two rules:

1. Put the worker functions in a separate module.
2. Protect the main process-only code with `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Assuming your three functions are moved to `worker.py`:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import worker

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.Process(target=worker.FirstWebScraping).start()
    mp.Process(target=worker.SecondWebscraping).start()
    mp.Process(target=worker.Calculations).start()
```

Comment: The worker.function might solve the problem , however when I want to import worker I get: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'worker'

Comment: @Felix You have to create `worker.py` and put it in the working directory of Jupyter.  `os.getcwd()` will tell you where that is.